# Dynamic hyperlink that filters a table based on the ActiveCell value (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a dynamic hyperlink that will filter a table on another sheet (Sheet15).

My goal is to have the user be able to select a cell on Sheet3 and have the VALUE of this cell be the filter on the other sheet.

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Type = msoHyperlinkRange And Target.Range.Address = "$S$15" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Sheet15.Visible = True
        Sheet15.ListObjects("Table17").Range.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value
        Sheet15.Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

However, when I click the hyperlink, the table is not filtered at all, so I gotta be doing something wrong.

Can anyone assist?

---

**UPDATE**

Here is updated code.

Cell S17 is now the value that I want to filter the table to:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Type = msoHyperlinkRange And Target.Range.Address = "$S$15" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Sheet15.Visible = True
        Sheet15.ListObjects("Table17").Range.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:=Sheet3.Range("S17").Value
        Sheet15.Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

But the issue remains. When I click they hyperlink, I will be brought to this other sheet, but the table is not filtered at all.

Comment: Works for me in a quick test.  Does anything happen when you click the link ?

Comment: When I click the link, it brings me to the correct sheet, however the table is not being filtered at all.

Comment: Try adding `Msgbox Sheet3.Range("S17").Value` to your code - is the value what you expect?

Comment: Where in my code do I add that?

Comment: Anywhere inside the `If` block

Comment: No, when I click the hyperlink there is no message box that pops up.

Comment: I'm not clear how that could happen: you say the table sheet is activated, so your `If` code must be executing.

Comment: Here's another thing-  Sheet15 is a hidden sheet. That's why I put the visible statements in the code. However, unless I manually unhide the sheet, the hyperlink doesn't work. So I feel like the code is just not working to begin with.

Comment: Can you share the workbook?  Via Dropbox or something...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129472/discussion-between-darren-and-tim-williams).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sticking to your original plans, and assuming column "A" is the one with cities names, place the following in your worksheet code pane

```
Option Explicit

Dim lastCell As Range '<--| declare a module scoped range variable to store the last cell selected by the user, if "valid"

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$S$15" Then Exit Sub '<-- do nothing if user selected cell with hyperlink
    Set lastCell = Intersect(Target, Columns("A")) '<-- change "Columns("A") to a named range with your cities
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If lastCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<--| no action if lastCell has not been properly set by 'Worksheet_SelectionChange()'

    If Target.Type = msoHyperlinkRange And Target.Range.Address = "$S$15" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Sheet15.Visible = True
        Sheet15.ListObjects("Table17").Range.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:=lastCell.Value '<--| set the criteria as 'lastCell' value
        Sheet15.Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

as per comments, you change  `Columns("A")` reference in `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` to your actual range with cities names (perhaps a *named range*)

Comment: I'm running into an issue with this because I am already running another Worksheet_SelectionChange event on this sheet.

Comment: What kind of issue?

Comment: "Compile error: Ambiguous name detected: Worksheet_SelectionChange"

Comment: You just merge them into a unique "Worksheet_SelectionChange()" sub. It'll begin with:     "If Target.Address <> "$S$15" Then Set lastCell = Intersect(Target, Columns("A")) " and goes on with the code you already have in it

Comment: @Darren, did you get through it?

Comment: Sort of. I'm still trying to work on it. I merged the two subs together, but now neither are working.

Comment: there must be only one `Worksheet_SelectionChange()`. Keep your _old_ one and just add as its first line after the header `If Target.Address <> "$S$15" Then Set lastCell = Intersect(Target, Columns("A"))`. If your _old_ `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` worked, then this _new_ one should, too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129477/discussion-between-darren-and-user3598756).

Comment: Hi, I sent you a Chat message

Answer (score 1):

Note: unless the hyperlink points to itself, `ActiveCell.Value` will be the *value at the link destination*: use `Target.Range.Value` if you want the value from the cell containing the link.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Type = msoHyperlinkRange And Target.Range.Address = "$S$15" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With Sheet15
            .Visible = True
            .ListObjects("Table17").Range.AutoFilter Field:=19, _
                                     Criteria1:=Target.Range.Value
            .Activate
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm so just want to clarify... The link just says "Click Here", so the value of the link doesn't actually change. What I'd like to do is have it so If the user clicks on a cell (Say "A13"), I want the link to filter the table based on A13's value. If that makes sense?

Comment: I'm not following you.  The user clicks on a link which just says "Click Here", so where is the value to filter the table by located?  At the destination of the hyperlink?  Is there a link in A13 ?

Comment: I think I'm seeing what you're getting at and where my error might be... OK, so say column A is a list of cities. If the user clicks on cell A13 which is "Chicago", he can then click the hyperlink which will bring him to another sheet. This table will be filtered to show just "Chicago". Is the error that the user would technically be clicking on two cells? So when the user clicks the hyperlink, it's not actually referencing "Chicago", it's just bringing him to the table. Is this right?

Comment: Yes - that's the issue.  You could replace the hyperlink with a button and use `Selection.Value` to get the selected city, or put hyperlinks on all of the city names...

Comment: This is an easy fix. I've created a cell in "S17" that has the value to filter the table to. Sticking with this example, the cell simply states "Chicago". I'll update my code so you can see what I mean...